# ArrayList onСlickListener не работает

Tags: android, arraylist

Я пытаюсь встроить в RecyclerView OnClickListener используя position через case.
Но почему-то при нажатии на itemView ничего не происходит.
Я так же использую Filtrable для RecyclerView.

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<SearchViewModel> exampleList;
    private List<SearchViewModel> exampleListFull;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static Context context;

    static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        RelativeLayout click_layout;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
            textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
            click_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.click_layout);
        }
    }
    public SearchAdapter(List<SearchViewModel> exampleList) {
        this.exampleList = exampleList;
        exampleListFull = new ArrayList<>(exampleList);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_item,
                parent, false);

        return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final SearchViewModel currentItem = exampleList.get(position);
        holder.textView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
        holder.click_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(context, ReaderActivity.class);
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER3);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER4);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER5);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER6);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER7);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER8);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER9);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        intent.putExtra("START_URL", Constants.CHAPTER10);
                        break;
                }
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return exampleList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }
    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<SearchViewModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(exampleListFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (SearchViewModel item : exampleListFull) {
                    if (item.getText2().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            exampleList.clear();
            exampleList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Может в логах что то есть? Может вы активити в манифесте не прописали?

Answer (score 1):

Из кода кажется, что все должно работать, кроме того что ваш адаптер это нечто, что стоит переписать.

`RecyclerView` не должен хранить в себе никакой логики, единственное что он должен уметь это показывать то что вы ему передали, на этом зона ответственности его заканчивается. Ваш клик листенер это жуть какая-то. Вот пример того как должен выглядеть адаптер `RecyclerView`:

```
class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final ItemClickListener listener;
    private final List<YourData> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public YourAdapter(ItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, null, false);
        return new ViewHolder(root);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void update(List<YourData> items){
        this.items.clear();
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private Button button;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }

        void bind(YourData data, ItemClickListener listener){
            button.setOnClickListener(v -> listener.onClick(data));
        }
    }
}
```

Интерфейс `OnItemClickListener`. Его должна реализовать ваша View в которой находится ваш адаптер.

```
interface ItemClickListener {

    void onClick(YourData data);
}
```

И обрабатывать клик должна Activity в зависимости от полученной модели.

Comment: Контекст не будет null. Он успешно проинициализируется при вызове конструктора Холдера. А так да, в коде интересное собрание оригинальных решений)

Comment: Ну наверное. Но тут вообще дич какая-то и сложно понять что вообще за проблема. С виду вроде все ок. Еще может быть проблема в XML

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте повесить слушателя на `holder.itemView.getRootView()`

Вполне вероятно ваш `layout` не получает нажатие, но его точно получит `rootView`.

```
holder.itemView.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { }
```