# Не удаётся заполнить recyclerview данными Json

Tags: java, android, json, recyclerview, jsoup

Приложение запускается, но список остаётся пустым

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
    
        private Document doc;
        private Thread secThread; // второстепенный поток
        private Runnable runnable;
        private ListView listView;
        private ArrayList<ListItemClass> arrayList;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            init();
        }
    
        private void init()
        {
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // getWeb();
                    refresh();
                }
            };
            secThread = new Thread(runnable);
            secThread.start();
    
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            // ArrayList<ListItemClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
            //list.add(new ListItemClass(arrayList, arrayList, arrayList));
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(arrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    
        public void refresh(){
            try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://yandex.ru/news/quotes/1.html").get();
                    Elements tables = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
                    Element our_table = tables.get(0);
                    Elements elements_from_table = our_table.children();
                    Element dollar = elements_from_table.get(0);
                    Elements dollar_elements = dollar.children();
                    Log.d("MyLog","Tbody size : " + our_table.children().get(0).text());
                    for(int i = 0;i < our_table.childrenSize();i++ )
                    {
                        ListItemClass items = new ListItemClass();
                        items.setData_1(our_table.children().get(i).child(0).text());
                        items.setData_2(our_table.children().get(i).child(1).text());
                        items.setData_3(our_table.children().get(i).child(2).text());
                        arrayList.add(items);
                       // Log.d("OneLog", list.get(0));
                    }
    
            } catch (Exception ex){
    
            }
        }
    }
```

адаптер:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.DataViewHolder>
{

    ArrayList<ListItemClass> text;

    public MyAdapter (ArrayList<ListItemClass> text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mTextView;
        TextView mTextView2;
        TextView mTextView3;

        public DataViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            mTextView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
            mTextView3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item3);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new DataViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(text.get(position).getData_1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(text.get(position).getData_2());
        holder.mTextView3.setText(text.get(position).getData_3());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return text.size();
    }
}
```

GitHub проекта:
https://github.com/Nikolui333/DollarRate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы запускаете поток и пытаетесь сразу же использовать данные, которые ещё не получены.
Обновлять содержимое адаптера необходимо по завершению задачи загрузки данных:

```
private void init() {
    // инициализируем всё что нужно
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // запускаем задачу загрузки
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // getWeb();
            refresh();
            // после загрузки уведомляем адаптер что данные изменились
            // делать это можно только в UI-потоке - поэтому
            // кидаем вызов в UI-поток любым способом
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            
            });
        }
            
            });
        }
    };
    secThread = new Thread(runnable);
    secThread.start();

}
```

Comment: Возникла небольшая проблема
adapter почему-то выделяется красным
// я добавил скриншот в вопрос

Comment: проблема решена:
final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(arrayList); // добавил final в эту строку и всё заработало

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: _добавил final_ - вы всё ещё на java7 ? https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: сейчас начал использовать java8, теперь работает без final

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаете в вашем адаптере  `private ArrayList<ListItemClass> arrayList;` но не инициализируете его никак. Соответственно при попытка адаптера задать значения RecyclerView он дергает метод arrayList.size(); и получает `NullPointerException()`.

Чтобы этого избежать инциализируйте ваш arrayList пустым списком:

```
private ArrayList<ListItemClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**P.S.** А еще вам рекомендация.
Ваш адаптер не должен ничего знать о существовании сети или других любых ваших внешних сущностях (Базы Данных, сети и прочей ерунде). Задача адаптера - рисовать RecyclerView ни больше не меньше.

Вы должны загружать, подготавливать и даже изменять данные за пределами адаптера, а в адаптер передавать уже полностью готовый для отображения список. В адаптере не должно быть ничего лишнего.

Таким образом если завтра ваши данные начнут грузиться из другого сервера или из кэша или вообще руками генерироваться вы не полезете менять код в ваш адаптер.

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161367/arraylist-on%D0%A1licklistener-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/1161376#1161376) есть пример адаптера

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но RecyclerView, почему-то всё равно не заполняется, подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это связанно и что с этим делать

Comment: по окночанию загрузки вызовите notifyDataSetChanged(). По идее этого вам не хватает. Если нет, то нужно больше информации.

Comment: я пока что не очень понял, откуда его вызывать, в адаптере такого метода нет, поэтому вызвать его не получается

Comment: Он есть в адаптере. Но в вашем примере сложно понять что и где. Я бы рекомендовал вам переписать сам адаптер. По примеру что я кинул. И полученный список просто передавать в метод update

Comment: адаптер, вроде +- такой же (я добавил его код в вопрос)

Comment: Ну вот когда вы получаете обновленные данные их нужно положить в адаптер. Вы никак не сообщаете адаптеру о том, что у вас обновились данные. вы добавляете их в список в активити, но адаптер об этом ничего не знает. Вам нужно создать метод который будет обновлять адаптер. См. мой пример. update и в него класть новый список

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111396/discussion-between---and-sergei-buvaka).